# Why do i need to call syscall write before syscall read to make it accept user input?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm

In the following x64 assembly program I am attempting to read a single character from the command line and then print it back. You will notice that I am performing what seems to be a useless write before actually reading the character.

This program compiles and when run and will halt, accept a character as input and after pressing return will write that character back and exit. Without the spurious write, it doesn't halt and accept user input and just exits. Why is that?

test.asm:

```
        global _start

        section .text
_start:
        mov r8, stack

        mov rax, 1  ; syscall write
        mov rdi, 1  ; 
        mov rsi, r8 ; 
        mov rdx, 1  ; Why do I need to do this write
        syscall     ; to make the following read work?

        mov rax, 0  ; syscall read
        mov rdi, 0  ; 
        mov rsi, r8 ; 
        syscall     ; Read a character from the cli.

        mov rax, 1  ; syscall write
        mov rdi, 1  ; 
        mov rsi, r8 ; 
        mov rdx, 1  ; 
        syscall     ; Print the character back to the cli.

        mov rax, 60 ; 
        mov rdi, 0  ; 
        syscall     ; Exit nicely.

        section .bss
stack:  resb 131072
```

I'm using `nasm` on Ubuntu 16.04 to compile like this:

```
nasm -f elf64 -o test.o test.asm
ld -m elf_x86_64 -o test test.o
./test
```

Comment: When you try without the write, do you set the rdx to 1 as well (mov rdx, 1)? If not, I believe that is the reason. You are not telling how much to read to your syscall

Comment: That does indeed seem to be the answer! I'm missing the fourth argument for the read call. Do you know of good documentation of x64 syscalls such as these?

Comment: The Linux kernel source code?

Comment: https://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/

Comment: Good, I'll set this as an answer so that we can close it. I usually use the link that @MichaelPetch posted.

Comment: Great resource thanks!

Comment: Use `strace ./test`  to see what system calls you process makes.  That would have shown you right away you forgot to set a non-zero size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you try without the first write, you do not set the `rdx` to 1 with `mov rdx, 1`.Therefore, you are not telling how much to read to your syscall. 
Here you can have a look at the 
[syscall table](https://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/)